# How can I convert a state component that has a toggle function to a stateless one in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert the following component to a functional one so I could use the react context API?

The JSX code for the component I want to convert

```
class pizzaModal extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: "small",
    showModal: true,
    selectedOrder: null
  }
  toggleHandler = (size)=> ()=>{
    this.setState({
            toggle: size
        });
  }
  addToOrders = (p)=>{
    this.setState(prevState=>({
      selectedOrder: p
    }))
  }
  
  render (){
    let attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer]
    if(this.state.toggle==='small'){
      attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer, styles.Small]
    }
    if(this.state.toggle==="medium"){
      attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer, styles.Medium]
    }
    if(this.state.toggle==="large"){
      attachedClasses=[styles.ImageContainer, styles.Large]
    }
    return (
      <Aux>
        <div className={styles.Pizzamodal}>
          <div className={styles.ModalContainer}>
            <div className={attachedClasses.join(' ')}>
              <img  src={this.props.image} alt="pizzapicture"/>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.DetailsContainer}>
              <div>
                <div className={styles.TextDetails}>
                  <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                  <p>{this.props.ingredients}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <div className={styles.Form}>
                <form className={styles.switchButton}>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="small" value="small" onChange={this.toggleHandler("small")}
                            checked={this.state.toggle==="small"}/>
                  <label for="small">Small</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="medium" value="medium" onChange={this.toggleHandler("medium")}
                            checked={this.state.toggle==="medium"}/>
                  <label for="medium">Medium</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="large" value="large" onChange={this.toggleHandler("large")}
                            checked={this.state.toggle==="large"}/>
                  <label for="large">Large</label>
                </form>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.orderButton}>
                  <button onClick={this.props.addToOrders}>Add to basket for ₦{this.props.price}</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>  
            <div className={styles.Navbar} onClick={this.props.clicked}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
          </div>
         
      </div>
      </Aux>
    )
  }
}
export default pizzaModal;
```

This is what I have done

```
const PizzaModal= (props) => {
  const [Selected, setSelected] = useState('small')
  
  const toggleHandler = (size)=>{
    setSelected({
            toggle: Selected
        });
  }
  /*const [orders, setOrders] = useContext([CartContext]);
  const addToOrders=()=>{
    const pizza = {name: this.props.name, ingredients: this.props.ingredients, image: this.props.image, price: this.props.price}
      setOrders([...orders, pizza])
  
  }*/
  
    let attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer]
    if(setSelected(Selected==='small')){
      attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer, styles.Small]
    }
    if(setSelected(Selected==="medium")){
      attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer, styles.Medium]
    }
    if(setSelected(Selected==="large")){
      attachedClasses=[styles.ImageContainer, styles.Large]
    }
    return (
      <Aux>
        <div className={styles.Pizzamodal}>
          <div className={styles.ModalContainer}>
            <div className={attachedClasses.join(' ')}>
              <img  src={props.image} alt="pizzapicture"/>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.DetailsContainer}>
              <div>
                <div className={styles.TextDetails}>
                  <h1>{props.name}</h1>
                  <p>{props.ingredients}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <div className={styles.Form}>
                <form className={styles.switchButton}>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="small" value="small" onChange={toggleHandler("small")}
                            checked={setSelected(Selected==='small')}/>
                  <label for="small">Small</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="medium" value="medium" onChange={toggleHandler("medium")}
                            checked={setSelected(Selected==='medium')}/>
                  <label for="medium">Medium</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="large" value="large" onChange={toggleHandler("large")}
                            checked={setSelected(Selected==='large')}/>
                  <label for="large">Large</label>
                </form>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.orderButton}>
                  <button >Add to basket for ₦{props.price}</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>  
            <div className={styles.Navbar} onClick={props.clicked}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
          </div>
         
      </div>
      </Aux>
    )
  
}
export default PizzaModal;
```

I have no error messages on my IDE or on the webpage but when I click on the button that toggles the modal on I get a blank white screen with no error messages.

Comment: Why do you have `setSelected` inside of your `if`s?

Comment: It was previously this.state.toggle. I am new to using hooks and I thought that would be the correct way to write it in a functional component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useState` hook returns the current value of the state variable and a function to change it. In your case with

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState('small')
```

you would use `selected` anywhere you previously would have used `this.state.selected` and use `setSelected()` anywhere you previously would have used `this.setState({ selected })`. So the first issue in your code is the misuse of the setter function when reading the state value.

When you want to pass a function to a component, you have to make sure you're passing the function and not a call to the function. For example

```
onChange={toggleHandler("large")}
```

will **immediately** get the return value of `toggleHandler("large")` and try to call that when the value changes. Your definition of `toggleHandler` doesn't return anything, so when you change your radio buttons, you're actually just trying to call `undefined` as a function, which of course doesn't work.

Also, the `onChange` handler of an input passes a synthetic event. You should use that to extract which radio button was pressed.

Try something like this:

```
const PizzaModal = (props) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState('small')
    
    const toggleHandler = (event) => {
      setSelected(event.target.value);
    }
  
    let attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer]
    if (selected === 'small')) {
      attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer, styles.Small]
    }
    if (selected === "medium")) {
      attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer, styles.Medium]
    }
    if (selected === "large")) {
      attachedClasses=[styles.ImageContainer, styles.Large]
    }
    return (
      <Aux>
        <div className={styles.Pizzamodal}>
          <div className={styles.ModalContainer}>
            <div className={attachedClasses.join(' ')}>
              <img  src={props.image} alt="pizzapicture"/>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.DetailsContainer}>
              <div>
                <div className={styles.TextDetails}>
                  <h1>{props.name}</h1>
                  <p>{props.ingredients}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <div className={styles.Form}>
                <form className={styles.switchButton}>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="small" value="small" onChange={toggleHandler} checked={selected === 'small'}/>
                  <label for="small">Small</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="medium" value="medium" onChange={toggleHandler} checked={selected === 'medium'}/>
                  <label for="medium">Medium</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="large" value="large" onChange={toggleHandler} checked={selected === 'large'}/>
                  <label for="large">Large</label>
                </form>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.orderButton}>
                  <button >Add to basket for ₦{props.price}</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>  
            <div className={styles.Navbar} onClick={props.clicked}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
          </div>
         
      </div>
      </Aux>
    )
  
}
export default PizzaModal;
```

For future reference, errors also come through in the browser's Javascript console (usually in the developer tools section). You can check there for errors. My guess is that some combination of trying to call `undefined` as a function and a render loop due to the `setSelected` calls is what was causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

couple of mistakes i spotted in your code see if this changes anything

1. You dont need a seperate toggleHandler function to change value of Selected that is what setSelected is there for.
2. You gave setSelected an object

```
setSelected({toggle: Selected});
```

instead u should give it the value of Selected

```
setSelected(Selected);
```

3. And in all the if statements

```
if(setSelected(Selected==='small'))
```

is wrong u just have to check

```
if(Selected==='small')
```

4.And finally in OnChange

```
onChange={toggleHandler("small")}
```

you can just call setSelected

```
onChange={() => setSelected("small")}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question. I appreciate it.

Comment: @ChinomsoJohnson My pleasure